# How to decrease audio volume below the minimum volume?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, sound-card, volume-mixer

I have a `3- C-Media USB Headphone Set`, a USB-Soundcard. I connected my head phones to it's headphone output. But even at level 2 of 100 in Windows 10, it is too loud. How do I make it even quieter?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the volume slider in windows  to adjust it, and try messing around with the knobs on your soundcard.

Comment: Question: How can I lower the volume below the minimum? 
Answer: Lower the volume.